# Is there any advantage to the Vagrant installer?

Tags: virtualbox, chef-infra, vagrant

Is there any substantive advantage (for the user) to using the downloadable installer for Vagrant over simply doing `gem install vagrant`, other than the fact the non-Rubyists can more easily get started using it?

I'm introducing Vagrant at a company I'm doing work for, and someone asked why I wasn't having everyone use the installer.  I prefer using `gem install vagrant` because (besides being more familiar and installing into "normal" places) they're going to need to do `gem install whatever` at some point anyway and might as well have everything set up.

I'd like to know, however, whether there are advantages (once everything is set up) of doing it one way or the other.

My suspicion is that the installer is the preferred method simply because it cuts down on support questions that distract the developers from contributing more to the project, and because it reduces the barrier to entry.  Those are both good reasons, but don't necessarily carry enough weight for me to have everyone switch now that they're all set up with Vagrant, Chef, VirtualBox, Ruby, Git, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage I see is when working with multiple versions of Ruby. Say you have RVM installed and `gem install vagrant` under a certain version of ruby / in a certain gemset. It won't be available as a gem unless you are using that version of ruby with that gemset.

However I suspect that using the installer will place the `vagrant` "binary" (ruby script) in /usr/local/bin or some such so that it is always available regardless of the currently active ruby.

for example, I installed the gem with rvm

`$ which vagrant
/Users/chrislundquist/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/vagrant`

Comment: $ ls -la `which vagrant`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  33 Mar 21 10:07 /usr/bin/vagrant -> /Applications/Vagrant/bin/vagrant

Comment: I think you mean `ls -ls \`which vagrant\``.  I had to use backslashes to keep from having the backticks from being interpreted as Markdown.  (It would also be helpful if Joel and Jeff allowed line breaks in these comments!)

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken then the installer will be the only way to install Vagrant from version 1.1 and up.

Comment: how would they prevent more traditional methods?

Comment: They could, for example, simply not build / publish a gem :)

It's probably less "the only way to install Vagrant" and more "the only supported way to install Vagrant"

Comment: From what I understand the gem won't be published in the future, only the installer will be offered.